# Kali Linux KDE not showing GUI for initial login

Tags: kali-linux, gui, display-manager, sddm, systemctl

this is my first Linux OS, and I'm trying to get more acquainted with my environment. I've got Kali Linux KDE working well, but when I first start linux, it boots into the terminal screen for TTY1 asking for my login and password. After I type that in, it boots into the Kali Linux GUI, but I'm pretty sure that initial login is supposed to have some sort of interface.

KDE uses `sddm` as the display manager which I have made sure I have installed along with `kde-config-sddm`. I've tried to use `systemctl enable sddm` to start `sddm` at boot, but I get a warning

> The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for the template units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl."

Now I know sddm is supposed to be able to be enabled, but I think this error has something to do with the fact that I have no sddm config file which according to the man pages is supposed to be located at `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d`. I don't even have a `/usr/lib/sddm` folder. Having reinstalled sddm, I think the sddm directory should exist, I know `apt-get` tells me its installed. KDE gives me a GUI for login settings, but I don't see anything to enable at startup.

Am I misunderstanding how a display manager is supposed to function? Would really appreciate anyone who could shed some light on this problem.

Comment: *"this is my first Linux OS"* You're starting with the wrong distribution, and it will cause you a lot of headaches and frustration. Get acquainted with Linux via Debian, Ubuntu, or CentOS first. See the link mentioned by @SivaPrasath.

Comment: Try installing a different DM e.g. LightDM

Comment: I should clarify, this is my first personal Linux build. I know Kali isn't for beginners but I've worked with Linux before and am familiar with how the operating system works. I'm by no means an expert and expected to struggle with it, but I wanted to as a learning experience. I'm trying to work on my Pentesting skills for CTFs and this is the perfect environment. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't really consider this a beginner question.